# Why does my Ubuntu desktop occasionally appear like this and how can I undo it?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu 21.04 and on occasion, my screen shows up like the following:

[image]

And I can't get out of it.  I've tried the escape keys and different alternatives but nothing gets me out except to just reboot. When I mouse over it, all I can do is close each panel. But closing all of them still leaves me in this state. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Have you tried super+A? (Where super is probably the key with a Windows logo.) I found that by looking in Settings -> Keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like Overview mode.

You can get into overview mode by the following actions:

- click the overview button in the top bar
- Press super-S  (super is sometimes known as the windows button)
- three finger pinch gesture on a touch screen
- install a 3 finger gesture touchpad extension

You can get out of overview mode by the following actions:

- click the overview button in the top bar
- press esc (works for me!)
- select one of the windows
- press super-S
- click the activities button in the top bar

Note that some of the gestures may work differently in X11 vs Wayland.
There are other ways to get in and out of overview mode, especially if you install a gesture extension or change your key bindings.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I can get it to the overview mode but I can never get out of it.  It seems to fail to get out of overview mode.  When I click on the activities button it seems to work fine, its when I click on Super S.  Also I'm not sure if it makes a difference but I'm using Dash To Panel

Comment: Cursory research indicates there have been bugs in overview historically (hopefully fixed now), and that some extensions may cause problems with overview, either of which could cause this.  You might want to try disabling all your extensions and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: If super-s is causing the problem, check your keybindings and make sure it isn't using a non-default setting that is making things worse.  Or unbind it completely so you don't bump it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I think I will take your last advice and just disable it.